# How to find a non-alphanumeric character and move it to the end of a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, find

I have the following string:

```
"string.isnotimportant"
```

I want to find the dot (it could be any non-alphanumeric character), and move it to the end of the string.

The result should look like:

```
"stringisnotimportant."
```

I am looking for a regular expression to do this job.

Comment: "I am looking for a regular expression to do this job"=> it sounds like you are looking for a member of stackoverflow to do this job! hehe

Comment: heheh, i am going to edit it.

Comment: There are plenty of string processing languages that you've needlessly eliminated with one sentence. I really dislike questions on SO where there is no research or reasonable attempt, and the questioner puts more emphasis on *how* to solve the problem than leaving it open to all possible solutions. I'd be a bit more understanding if you already had a code base that you had to integrate with (in which case your language choices may be limited), but seeing as there's no code posted here, this excuse becomes inexcusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re

>>> string = "string.isnotimportant"
#I explain a bit about this at the end
>>> regex = '\w*(\W+)\w*' # the brackets in the regex mean that item, if matched will be stored as a group
#in order to understand the re module properly, I think your best bet is to read some docs, I will link you at the end of the post
>>> x = re.search(regex, string)

>>> x.groups() #remember the stored group above? well this accesses that group.
               #if there were more than one group above, there would be more items in the tuple
('.',)

#here I reassign the variable string to a modified version where the '.' is replaced with ''(nothing).
>>> string = string.replace('.', '')
>>> string += x.groups()[0] # here I basically append a letter to the end of string
```

The `+=` operator appends a character to the end of a string. Since strings don't have an .append method like lists do, this is a handy feature. `x.groups()[0]` refers to the first item(only item in this case) of the tuple above.

```
>>> print string

"stringisnotimportant."
```

about the regex:

"\w" Matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore: a through z, A through Z, 0 through 9, and '_'.

"\W" Matches any non-alphanumeric character. Examples for this include '&', '$', '@', etc.

https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?csw=1

http://python.about.com/od/regularexpressions/a/regexprimer.htm

Comment: could you please explain string += x.groups()[0] to me as I am a beginner. thanks

Comment: I just have 14 reputations, so I am unable. but as soon i reach 15 that is the requirement, I will do that. thanks a lot

Comment: This gets the job done, but isn't doing it only through a regex. It's using regex followed by string concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
inp = "string.isnotimportant"
re.sub('(\w*)(\W+)(\w*)', '\\1\\3\\2', inp)
```

Comment: I know that what ('\\1\\3\\2') it does, but I want to understand the logic. could you please explain this expression.

Comment: Sure. The second bit is really `\1\3\2`, which are backreferences to the first 3 capture groups, but the backslashes must be escaped (or you can use a raw string with `r'\1\2\3'`). This is very similar to Totem's regex - it matches 0 or more word characters with `\w*`, then 1 or more non-word characters with `\W+`, then the 1st one again. The `()`s capture each of these 3 sections. The `\1\3\2` just reorders the 3 sections to put the middle one, with its non-word characters at the end.